# Bugged PrimEng datatable change detection after upgrade Angular to 4

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

After my upgrade from Angular 2 to Angular 4, primeng datatable is bugged because it does not see changes in list which is passed as data.

For example, I have a datatable:

```
<p-dataTable selectionMode="single" [resizableColumns]="true" [rows]="20" [paginator]="true" [value]="queuedJobs" [rowHover]="true" [globalFilter]="gb" [style]="{'cursor':'pointer'}">

</p-dataTable>
```

and when I modify "queuedJobs" array, datatable content does not change how it was in Angular 2. How to solve it? Do you have the same bug?

Regards 
Mateusz

Answer (score 1):

We do have the same issue in our project. [I think the answer lies in the way PrimeNG handles value changes](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/datatable/datatable.ts#L773):

```
@Input() get value(): any[] {
    return this._value;
}

set value(val:any[]) {
    this._value = val ? [...val] : null;
    this.handleDataChange(); //filter the value 
}
```

My guess is that somehow, the `<p-dataTable/>`'s internal array value is not the same instance of the array that you are modifying, so changes are *not* reflected.

A temporary workaround is to force the array to be a new instance every time you modify it:

```
//...after you've done your array updates
this.queuedJobs = this.queuedJobs.slice(); // does a shallow clone of the array
```

Now, the `<p-dataTable/>`'s `handleDataChange` method is called, and the data is rerendered.

**This is not a permanent solution.** Hopefully, the next version of primeng will fix this issue.

**EDIT**: I now realize that it is due to the way they set the array internally:

```
this._value = val ? [...val] : null;
```

This essentially clones the array, therefore your changes will never be reflected. Definitely a bug.

**Edit 2**: as talpaz pointed out, [this is a part of the design](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4-0-0-rc4-released/), so you *must* create a new array after adding or removing elements.

Comment: Creating the new array resolves the issue. Non-intuitive functionality if this is meant to be by design, imho.

Comment: @NullԀʇɹ92065 As of 4.1.0, you can now also specify `[immutable]="false"` on the table to achieve the old behavior.

Comment: @"Michael Kucinski" Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a change "by design"...

see
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2606

Comment: Read also [a comment about restoring the requested option](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2606#issuecomment-312006250)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else coming to face the same issue, please go through [the part where they describe change detection](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable)

> DataTable either uses setter based checking or ngDoCheck to realize if the underlying data has changed to update the UI. This is configured using the immutable property, when enabled (default) setter based detection is utilized so your data changes such as adding or removing a record should always create a new array reference instead of manipulating an existing array as Angular does not trigger setters if the reference does not change. For example, u**se slice instead of splice when removing an item or use spread operator instead of push method when adding an item**. On the other hand, setting immutable property to false removes this restriction by using ngDoCheck with IterableDiffers to listen changes without the need to create a new reference of data. Setter based method is faster however both methods can be used depending on your preference. Note that immutable property also defines how DataTable treats the data, for example when immutable is enabled sorting does not mutate the original data but creates a new array of sorted data.

Also after this there is an example for paginator reset

```js
export class DataTableDemo implements OnInit {

    cars: Car[];

    first: number = 0;

    constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.cars = cars);
    }

    reset() {
        this.first = 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [(first)]="first">
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>

<button type="button" (click)="reset()" label="Reset"></button>
```

These options should cover you good!

Answer (score 0):

I have added a [immutable]="false" in p-datatable tag in html. It worked for me.